# Why is SoapUI generating spurious traffic?

Tags: soapui, performance-testing

This is my first time using SoapUI (v4.6.0 on Windows Server 2003 R2 - x64), and I'm performing a simple test of an HTTP REST API on two different servers.  My IT department has the servers behind an Equalizer cluster, and I've done individual performance testing with each server, where one or the other is disabled at the Equalizer.  I wanted to get a baseline for each server before enabling them both.

What's curious, is that when a server is disabled at the Equalizer, I see unexpected CPU and network activity on it.  It's not HTTP traffic, because the web server access/error logs are quiet.  And when the SoapUI test completes, the activity stops.

Since I'm new to SoapUI, I'm wondering if it does some type of multicast onto the network, for whatever reason, even though I'm doing an HTTP test.  Does anyone know if that's the case, or how else to explain the mysterious traffic?

EDIT:

Hmmm... I just installed Wireshark on the SoapUI server and ran it for a few seconds while I had a test active.  Under Statistics->Endpoints->IPv4, I see that the majority of the traffic goes between the SoapUI server and the Equalizer, with just a few packets going directly to the server under test.  So maybe it's not SoapUI after all, and the Equalizer is doing something unexpected.  I'm going to check with the IT guys.

Comment: By 'Equalizer cluster', do you mean load balancer? I think your observation is reasonable, soapUI is a simple HTTP client in this case, the 'equalizer' should grab attention and as it employes more complex logic.

Comment: Yes, it's a load balancer.  Tomorrow I'll see if I can install Wireshark on the server that's been disabled at the Equalizer, to see who is sending it the unexpected traffic... guess I should have done that first.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This was a test-setup mis-configuration issue.  We had MongoDB installed on each server, configured to read data from the *other* server.  This question can be closed as *d'oh!*